# Creating a dynamic multidimensional array from update_post_meta

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional array for an events calendar, where the user can add days dynamically. The end result should look something like this, where the date is the parent key and the times are child keys of the date:

***Date: 1 March 2018 | Start Time: 9.00am | End Time: 11.00am***

***Date: 2 March 2018 | Start Time: 9.30am | End Time: 11.30am***

My HTML form inputs are as follows and are cloned using jQuery:

```
<input type="text" name="training_day[][date]">
<input type="text" name="training_day[date][][start_time]">
<input type="text" name="training_day[date][][end_time]">
```

I am saving the form data to post like so:

```
<?php
     if (!empty($_POST['training_day'])) {
         update_post_meta($pid, 'training_day', $_POST['training_day']) 
     }
```

I am querying using the below and the print_r() result is this:

```
$training_day = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'training_day', true);
print_r($training_day);

Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [date] => Thursday, 1 March, 2018 ) 
    [date] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [start_time] => 9.00am ) 
        [1] => Array ( [end_time] => 11.00am ) 
        [2] => Array ( [start_time] => 9.30am ) 
        [3] => Array ( [end_time] => 11.30am ) 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( [date] => Friday, 2 March, 2018 ) 
)
```

But surely I need it something like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [date] => Thursday, 1 March, 2018 ) 
    [date] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [start_time] => 9.00am ) 
        [1] => Array ( [end_time] => 11.00am )
    ) 
[1] => Array ( [date] => Friday, 2 March, 2018 ) 
   [date] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [start_time] => 9.30am ) 
        [1] => Array ( [end_time] => 11.30am ) 
    )
)
```

I have tried a variety of options of adding [] in various positions on the name attributes of start_time and end_time inputs without any luck.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" value="13:00" name="training_day[date][0][start_time]">
<input type="text" value="15:00" name="training_day[date][0][end_time]">
<input type="text" value="11:00" name="training_day[date][1][start_time]">
<input type="text" value="16:00" name="training_day[date][1][end_time]">
```

results in:

```
array(1) {
  ["training_day"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["date"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(5) "13:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(5) "15:00"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(5) "11:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(5) "16:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should be all you need, only declaring a start and end time. Other values might overwrite previous keys.

Also, why would you want multiple start and end times? We might be missing context.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. It saves the dates correctly but overwrites the  first set of times with the second set of inputs. Basically: 
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [date] => Thursday, 1 March, 2018 ) [date] => Array (    [start_time] => 9.30am [end_time] => 11.30am ) 
   [1] => Array ( [date] => Friday, 2 March, 2018 ) 
)

Comment: I have put in multiple start and end times because each event could be  any number of days and each day could possible start and end at different times. Your edit is what I am currently using for the times. I need the date to be saved as well.

Comment: @DakotaDC3 this gives me some context, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @DakotaDC3 as you can see I added a `0` key to the array, this means the array will group all items with `0` under that key.

If you wanted to add another day(or session), you would want to add another set of inputs with a `1`, so it would create another array index. Using the sample code above, you can easily group by different ranges and process them accordingly.

Comment: @DakotaDC3 if it works, don't forget to mark this as the answer.